# Function to convert numbers over 1000 to 1k etc. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

G'day,

The function is coded, but it's on the stage frame. I'm looking to get it converted into a more dynamic function so I can just call it on all my textfields.

Here's the code:

```
function numtolet():void
{
    output.text = String(int(earner  * 100) / 100);
    if (earner >= 1000 && earner < 1000000)
    {
        output.text = String(int((earner/1000)  * 100) / 100 + "k");
    }
    else if (earner >=1000000 && earner < 1000000000)
    {
        output.text = String(int((earner/ 1000000) * 100 ) / 100 + " M");
    }
}
```

I'm looking to turn the 'output.text' portion into a variable that changes based on the text field calling the function and 'earner' to the variable the textfield reads.

Cheers,

-Aidan.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better write your function as proper function that can `return` a `String` value to assign to a `text` property or use elsewhere. Also, you should use a pattern that is easily extendable to bigger prefixes, should you need them. Say, I have found a game with a `W` prefix being used, which is one beyond the common "yotta" prefix, and there was a set of subsequent prefixes as well. So, this is how you should devise such a function:

```
function numtolet(x:Number):String {
    const prefixes:Vector.<String> = Vector.<String>(["","k","m","g","t"]); 
    // add more to taste. Empty prefix is used if the number is less than 1000
    var y:Number=x;
    var i:int=1;
    // provided x>0, if not, store a minus somewhere and attach later
    while((y>=1000) && (i<prefixes.length)) {
        y=y/1000;
        i++;
    } 
    // there, you have just divided X by 1000 a couple of times and selected the prefix
    var s:String = y.toFixed(2)+prefixes[i-1];
    // if there was a minus, add it here: s="-"+s;
    return s;
}
```

Then you just call it like this:

```
output.text=numtolet(earner);
```

Comment: Cheers for your help Vesper, but "function numtolet(x:Number):String {" is returning a compiler error "A constructor cannot specify a return type".

Comment: This means, rename the function. This error means `numtolet` is the name of your class, and a function with name identical to the class should be its constructor, and these can't return a value.

Comment: Changed the function name but still getting the error.

Comment: This means you've mixed something up in your code. This function should reside in the class description, be nested inside the class but not inside any function. Weird I say, unless I've mixed up something in the function's syntax.

Comment: It is it's own function within the class. Do I need to import anything to use the function? Sprites or anything?

Comment: Scrap the class then, use `package ... { public function numtolet(x:Number):String {...} }` structure. The only code that should remain in the AS file should be the function body. No, you don't need to import a thing for this function to work.

Comment: in the while condition it should say (y>=1000) i guess, otherwise it's one off

Comment: Okay, this is the case with AS3 numbers sometimes, say 1.0e24 indeed reaches true at some step of this algorithm. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the CHANGE event:

```
output.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, numtolet);

function numtolet(e:Event):void
{
    output.text = String(int(earner  * 100) / 100);
    if (earner >= 1000 && earner < 1000000)
    {
        output.text = String(int((earner/1000)  * 100) / 100 + "k");
    }
    else if (earner >=1000000 && earner < 1000000000)
    {
        output.text = String(int((earner/ 1000000) * 100 ) / 100 + " M");
    }
}
```

This will make the function run every time the text is changed by a user, but you'd probably want to add a few conditional (if)'s to the function, or use a variable to keep track of the curent number. When the number converts to 1k, how does it know what do to at 1000k?

Feel free to ask if you need help on this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a keyboard event to detect the enter button being pressed.

Comment: The function is changed after a timer event (every 1 second). I haven't finished with the conversions, I plan on going up at least another ten levels in. I was looking for a more general function that converts any series of numbers to from any variable to a readable number, which will then be utilized by various text fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `CHANGE` event like Neguido said, and add listeners to different text fields, you can use `e.target.text =` to change the text in the calling text field.
To target a different variable for each text field is more difficult, because you cant pass extra arguments into the event handlers, and you cant add your own variables/properties to textFields. You could stick each textField into a parent MovieClip and then create variables in there like `MovieClip1.earner = 0` and retrieve the values with `e.target.parent.earner`. You could also write a dynamic extension to the TextField class where you add custom variables. Alternatively you could use a `switch` statement in your event handler to use different variables for different callers.

Comment: Even if you're only using one TextField, make sure you give the first part of this answer a good read for future reference, Aidan. The e.target variable adds to the whole purpose of functions, being that they are 're-usable sets of code'. The function would be able to, like @Scab said, be used regardless of which TextField called the event. It's always good to add versatility to your functions and keep your overall programming as neat and minimal as possible, and - by that I mean - never ever ever have more than one part of your code doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I can definitely use the e.target.text line. That was more what I was after when I created this question. I'm still really new to OOP and as3 in general and was looking for a way to access the textfield calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick function I wrote up for something else.  It can easily be adapted to larger numbers by adding another if statement and adding 000 to the number.  It also doesn't include the output display, but that can very easily be added as well.  Hope it helps!

Call the function via numToLet(earner).

```
     function numToLet(x) {
        if (x > 1000000000000000000) {
            x = x / 1000000000000000000
            x = Number(x.toFixed(2));
            return x + "Quin"; 
        }
        if (x > 1000000000000000) {
            x = x / 1000000000000000
            x = Number(x.toFixed(2));
            return x + "Quad"; 
        }
        if (x > 1000000000000) {
            x = x / 1000000000000
            x = Number(x.toFixed(2));
            return x + "Tril"; 
        }
        if (x > 1000000000) {
            x = x / 1000000000
            x = Number(x.toFixed(2));
            return x + "Bil"; 
        }
        if (x > 1000000) {
            x = x / 1000000
            x = Number(x.toFixed(2));
            return x + "Mil"; 
        }
        if (x < 1000000) {
            x = Number(x.toFixed(2));
            return x; 
        }

    }
```